# How to ensure figure comes AFTER the text where it is placed?

Tags: floats

I am using the `figure` environment to place my figures in my document. At this point, I am using the `[hbt]` option because I don't necessarily care about where the figure is placed --- so long as it is placed AT/AFTER where I declare it.

Is there a way to ensure that the figure is placed at/after where I declare it while still allowing it to float to the best location (`[hbt]`)?

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
\usepackage{flafter}
```

This is part of the base LaTeX code and does exactly what you ask.

Note however that whether or not you use `flafter` you should use `[hbtp]` rather than `[hbt]` not including `p` significantly increases the chance of all floats going to the end of the document.